# (Mac OS X) Do I need Library/Application Support/BootCamp/WindowsSupport.dmg?

Tags: macos, mac, boot-camp

I recently used Migration Assistant and it left me with some odds and ends to sort through, including some obselete Bootcamp data.

Do I need Library/Application Support/BootCamp/WindowsSupport.dmg now that I no longer have a Windows partition?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't plan on using BootCamp on that computer, you don't need to have that file. If you do ever want to use BootCamp, you'll need the file IIRC.